# fixturelist generator issue java

Tags: java, dictionary, arraylist

## Overview

So I'm trying to create a fixture list generartor. The program is not factoring in home and away fixtures for simplicity. The program uses the generateFixtures() method to generate fixtures per round and is then repeated for a specified amount of rounds till all the fixtures have been generated.

## How the program works

The generateFixtures method is passed an arrayList in its parameters with all the teams in that division that need generating fixtures for that round. Also the arrayList passed will always contain 20 teams. Then two strings are created which hold the values of a random team of the within in the arraylist. generateFixtures() then checks if either of the teams have already been used for that round using the alreadyUsed() method. It also checks if either teams are already fixtured in terms of the whole season (but I will explain this part in more detail later). It then does a further check to test to ensure the two teams are not the same (in that team1 == team2). When all the checks are complete it puts the two teams into the fixture list map, which is called fixturesDone. And also puts the two teams into the 'used' arraylist so that the two teams aren't used again for that round. It keeps repeating the while loop until all the teams are fixtured (in that the arraylist 'used' size is  greater than or equal to 19). Then a loop is setup in the main method to keep looping the generateFixtures() method until all fixtures are completed for the whole season.

## The Issue

The issue occurs in the 'fixturesDone' map or the alreadyFixtured() method. Honestly not sure which one could be causing the problem. When I print out the fixtures directly from the generateFixtures method from inside the if statement the fixtures are generated but there are often duplicate fixtures, while when I print out the fixtures from the 'fixturesDone' map there are no duplicate fixtures but there only seems to be 20 fixtures present, and its always 20 aswell which suggests that I probably messed something up in one of the loops. I've been tackling this problem for a couple of hours now and I am just really confused so any help would be greatly appreciated :)

## Code

Anyway bearing in my mind what I have said here is the necessary code, good luck.

```
public static void generateFixtures(ArrayList<String> al){

    ArrayList<String> used = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(used.size() <= 19){

    String team = al.get(showRandomInteger(0, 19, r));  
    String team2 = al.get(showRandomInteger(0, 19, r));
    if(alreadyUsed(used, team, team2) == false && alreadyFixtured(fixturesDone, team, team2) == false && !team.equals(team2)){
        fixturesDone.put(team, team2);
        used.add(team);
        used.add(team2);

        System.out.println(team + "vs. " + team2);

    }
    }

    System.out.println("\n New week \n");
}

public static boolean alreadyFixtured(Map <String, String> m, String team1, String team2){
    if(m.containsKey(team1) || m.containsKey(team2)){

            for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : m.entrySet()){

                if((entry.getKey().equals(team1) && entry.getValue().equals(team2)) || (entry.getKey().equals(team2) && entry.getValue().equals(team1)) ){
                    return true;
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }



    }else{
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {

    for(int i = 0; i <= 19; i++){
        generateFixtures(ReadXML(1));
    }

    System.out.println("\n Map version: ");

    for(Map.Entry <String, String> entry : fixturesDone.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " vs. " + entry.getValue());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `alreadyFixtured` logic is messed up.  It will only check the first entry in your map because you return true or false after only checking the first entry in your foreach loop.  Really you could just replace your code with:

```
if(m.containsKey(team1))
    return m[team1].equals(team2);
if(m.containsKey(team2))
    return m[team2].equals(team1);

return false;
```

But you also need a better data structure than this `fixturesDone` map.  Which leads me to my next point.

Your fixturesDone map (I'm assuming is global) is pretty much useless. You'll only be able to compare to at most 2 previous rounds since each key can only appear once in the map, and you overwrite half the key-value pairs each call to generateFixtures.  You should change your presumed `Map<String, String> fixturesDone` to a `Map<String, ArrayList<String>>`, in which case you will need to change your `alreadyFixtured` logic to:

```
if(m.containsKey(team1))
    return m[team1].contains(team2);
if(m.containsKey(team2))
    return m[team2].contains(team1);

return false;
```

You should also change your team selection to do-while loops:

```
String team, team2;
do{
    team = al.get(showRandomInteger(0, 19, r));
}while(used.contains(team));

do{
    team2 = al.get(showRandomInteger(0, 19, r));
}while(used.contains(team2) || team2.equals(team1));
```

Then the subsequent if statement can be written as just:

```
if(!alreadyFixtured(fixturesDone, team, team2))
```

However, you do still have the potential problem that in a particular round there only remain teams that have already played each other in which case your code will loop indefinitely.  This is not as trivial as it sounds.  It might be easier to generate all of the fixtures in a sort of round-robin fashion and then randomize the order in which those fixtures occur.

Comment: Yeah, I've decided that even if I do use your improvements, which are very useful. There will still be this problem. After coming to realise that generating a fixture list is more complicated than I first thought I think I will take your advice and use round robin and then randomize the order. Thinking about it this is a lot simpler mathematically and should also lead to cleaner code. I will be posting the new code shortly so other users who stumble on a similar problem can see a better solution :)